# CSS transition won't run without `setTimeout`

Tags: javascript, css

I've used JS to set the opacity on an element to 0, then set an opacity transition, and finally set the opacity to 1. I'd expect to see the element instantly disappear and then fade back in. Instead, nothing happens.

However, if I add a `setTimeout` before setting the transition and setting opacity to 1, the transition does trigger. What's happening here? Are browsers batching CSS changes? Is there a better way than the `setTimeout` hack?

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpk5en54/2/

```
<span>abeclc</span>
<button>Go</button>

var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function () {
    span.style.transition = '';
    span.style.opacity = '0';
    //setTimeout(function () {
        span.style.transition = 'opacity 2s';
        span.style.opacity = '1';
    //}, 100);
};
```

Comment: Yes, browsers will "batch" CSS changes for performance reasons. Instead of `setTimeout()`, you can use `requestAnimationFrame()` if it's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger a reflow:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lpk5en54/3/

```
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function () {

    span.style.transition = '';
    span.style.opacity = '0';
 //   setTimeout(function () {
    var foo = span.offsetTop
        span.style.transition = 'opacity 2s';
        span.style.opacity = '1';
  //  }, 100);
};
```